# Does the power state of an electrical device affect its likelihood of being struck by lightning?

Tags: electric-current, lightning

Holidaying in the tropics, I have come across the following behaviours, all intended to reduce the likelihood of attracting a lightning strike when in a storm.

1. Turning off the CD player/ radio in the car.
2. When sitting at home, on the porch outside, moving smartphones inside the house.
3. Disabling the automatic fill feature of the 2 x 250 litre water bottles at the top of a 9 metre water tower, for fear of damaging the water pump in the well below.

Do any of these behaviours have merit?

Comment: I would guess the first 2 behaviors have little effect on lightning. 2. could be to simply protect phones from rain.  3. Having the machines offline may protect them from damage in the case of a lightning strike while not changing the probability of a lightning strike.

Comment: Many ham radio operators physically disconnect their antenna (on a big pole/tower) from their radio, but more to keep a strike from coming down into the house. If a device is not grounded, it is less likely to be struck and less likely to have significant current dumped through it, resulting in its death...